# NG0203 error while using ngbTooltip directive as manual trigger in custom qtip directive

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

#### Bug description:

I have a directive `dewQtip` in qtip.directive.ts which basically does the same thing as ngbTooltip directive along with some customizations that are to be maintained in the entire organization ecosystem. In the directive, I am manually triggering the tooltip to open :
      `this.ngbToolTip.open();`

But right above this I am setting the `ngbToolTip` as:

```
this.ngbToolTip = new NgbTooltip(
        this._elementRef,
        this._renderer,
        this.injector,
        this.viewContainerRef,
        this.ngbTooltipConfig,
        this.ngZone,
        document,
        this._cdRef,
        this._appRef
      );
```

And this is where the error generates from.

#### Error:

Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`.  Find more at [here](https://angular.io/errors/NG020)

#### Call Stack

The error seems to stem from

```
export function ngbPositioning() {
    const rtl = inject(NgbRTL);
```

So it goes from,

```
export function ngbPositioning() {         
    const rtl = inject(NgbRTL);
```

in [positioning.ts](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/util/positioning.ts#L215)
^
^
`private _positioning = ngbPositioning();`  in [tooltip.ts](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/ade9e4fc33411b2cecf38263839706a8128b369d/src/tooltip/tooltip.ts#L179)
^
^
`this.ngbToolTip = new NgbTooltip(.....)`  in /qtip.directive/

#### Link to minimally-working StackBlitz that reproduces the issue:

Have created a minimal reproduction with the custom directive in question.
[Reproduction Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byokwg?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

#### Versions of Angular, ng-bootstrap and Bootstrap:

Angular: 16.1.7

ng-bootstrap: 15.1.2

Bootstrap: 5.2.3

#### Workarounds:

Still investigating.

I tried downgrading to the previous versions of @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap (since the issue itself was faced after ng upgrade 11 --> 16) but these versions are not supported by angular 16 anymore. Yet to find any workarounds so far.